# iOS 8 & AVFoundation: How To Dim Background Audio?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, audio, avfoundation

I've googled around and looked through SO but I cannot find a solid answer on how to do something that seems very simple.

Do you know how I can dim the background audio programmatically with iOS 8 and AVFoundation?

My app will let users play audio (from another app) but at certain times we need to dim the audio to play an audio from our app.

I know we need to to use an AVFoundationSession object but I'm not sure how to grab the background audio and adjust its volume settings.

Any advice or insight would be great!

Swift/Obj-c answers welcome!

*Solution*

```
//Manages dimming and resuming background audio
class O_Audio
{
    class func dimBackgroundAudio()
    {
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DuckOthers, error: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS manages that for you. Set the [AVAudionSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback) category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` and use the `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers` option.

You can set this in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: Use `setActive` on the audio session to deactivate it after you've played the audio. Ensure that this is occuring.